# Why does imaplib return a lone parenthesis after each email?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

Overview: **When fetching an email via imap with `imaplib` in Python, the returned payload is a list of email tuples...with a single byte `b')'` inbetween each tuple.**

I use your standard imaplib `fetch` call given a comma-separated byte string of UIDs:

```
resp, data = mailbox.fetch(b'1,2,3'), 'RFC822')
```

However, `data` looks like:

```
[ 
  (b'1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE TO CC FROM SUBJECT)] {181}',
    b'Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 16:08:07 -0700 From: Blah Blah\r\n\r\n'
  ),
  b')',
  (b'1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (DATE TO CC FROM SUBJECT)] {181}',
    b'Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 16:08:07 -0700 From: Blah Blah\r\n\r\n'
  ),
  b')',
  ...
]
```

So now, when I iterate over that list, I have to skip over every other element to avoid the `b')'`. Obviously, that's not hard...but it feels like I'm doing something wrong, or that `imaplib` should be better parsing this closing parenthesis.

**Why is that parenthesis there, and is there a way to use IMAP more correctly to eliminate it?**

---

Thoughts:

Looks like the closing parenthesis is a [built-in part of RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.4) but from what I understand of that spec (which isn't much, honestly) the parenthesis isn't supposed to come until the END of the payload, which to my mind would be after all the messages are read.

Edit: By the way, this parenthesis shows up whether or not you're fetching multiple messages...even if you follow [imaplib's own example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example), you get back data looking like `[(headers, payload), b')']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that imaplib is not a parser, but a simple low-level library.  When you make a fetch request, the responses for each message look something like this:

```
* 27 FETCH (A A-DATA B B-DATA C C-DATA)\r\n
```

That is, the response to fetch is a list of *pairs* of data items.  The parentheses indicate to a parser that this is a (possibly) variable length list of data items.  Specifically, when you request a body, it looks like this, conceptually:

```
* 27 FETCH (RFC822 BODYDATA)\r\n
```

When an IMAP server wishes to send a blob of data that might contain newlines or other weird characters, it uses an escaping mechanism that the standard refers to as literals.  It provides a byte count in curly brackets, a new line pair, then a raw dump of that many bytes. Then the server goes back to what the command it was sending.  This looks like this:

```
* 27 FETCH (RFC822 {457}\r\n___457 bytes of body data here___)\r\n
```

`imaplib` only knows about newlines and literals, but it otherwise doesn't parse responses beyond telling you what kind it is.  It breaks it up into pieces like this:

```
* 27 FETCH (RFC822 {457}\r\n
___457 bytes of body data here___
)\r\n
```

These three lines are the three parts of the response you see:  The stuff before the literal, the literal itself, and the stuff after the literal.  In this case, it's a single parenthesis to close the list that got opened in the first part.  If you requested multiple fetch pieces that needed literals to transmit, you'd see even more parts.

I for one would love if imaplib was more of a parser, but it really is just a low level access mechanism.  For more complex work, a parser needs to be built on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I agree - it seems so straightforward to parse each individual message component into a single object...fields would be the UID, command, RFC#, byte size, literal str, and list close `b')'`...maybe there's a superior python library for it but I don't know of it.

Comment: Parsing is surprisingly difficult, especially for extension commands. You can do a fairly low level parse easily, but providing high level objects requires knowledge of any extensions that may need to be supported.    Some libraries with high level representations (like php) can't support anything that wasn't designed into it.